# Unique ID in PostgreSQL 9.4 table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to insert unique ID record into PostgreSQL 9.4 table.

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_HISTORY(ID, ACCOUNT_ID, USERNAME, COMMENT, CREATED) VALUES (?, (select ID from ACCOUNT where USER_NAME = ?), ?, ?, CURRENT_DATE)
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_HISTORY(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 ACCOUNT_ID INTEGER,
 USERNAME TEXT,
 COMMENT TEXT,
 CREATED DATE
)
;

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP8 ON ACCOUNT_HISTORY (ACCOUNT_ID)
;
```

How I can generate unique ID for every insert query?

Answer (score 2):

Use `serial`:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_HISTORY (
   ID SERIAL,
   ACCOUNT_ID INTEGER,
   USERNAME TEXT,
   COMMENT TEXT,
   CREATED DATE
);
```

Then, do not include it in the `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_HISTORY(ACCOUNT_ID, USERNAME, COMMENT, CREATED)
    SELECT ID, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_DATE
    FROM ACCOUNT 
    WHERE USER_NAME = ?;
```

EDIT:

If you have data in the table (so you don't want to just drop it):

```
create temporary table temp_account_history as
    select *
    from account_history;

drop account_history;

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_HISTORY (
   ID SERIAL,
   ACCOUNT_ID INTEGER,
   USERNAME TEXT,
   COMMENT TEXT,
   CREATED NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_HISTORY(ACCOUNT_ID, USERNAME, COMMENT, CREATED)
    SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, USERNAME, COMMENT, CREATED
    FROM TEMP_ACCOUNT_HISTORY;
```

Note that this also gives `CREATED` a default value, so you don't have to include that in subsequent inserts either.

Comment: What SQL statement should I use for inset using this solution. How I need to edit my SQL query?

Comment: @PeterPenzov . . . Re-create the table correctly.  If you already have data in the table, copy it to a temporary table.  Remove the first table.  Redefine it and insert the data back into it.

Comment: One additional question is the a similar solution for Oracle database?

Comment: @PeterPenzov No, but you can use CAPITALS if you want to.

Comment: CAPITALS? Can you give me some additional information?

Comment: @PeterPenzov . . . The answer would be pretty much the same for Oracle.  You would need to fix the data types and the default creation date uses `sysdate`.